# How do I redirect_to a route thats inside of a namespace in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces, rails-routing

I have a project where I am using rails as my backend and I have a model called "Projects". I am trying to do a simple redirect to my index action after deleting a single project but I keep getting errors saying that the path does not exist. I believe the error is because my controller is nested in some namespaces like so:

```
namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      root :to => 'projects#index'
      resources :videos
      resources :projects
      resources :project_types
    end
  end
```

I have a root inside of the namespace, but I am unable to successfully redirect to it. I have run `rails routes` so I can see that the `api_v1_root` route exists but I don't know how to redirect to it. My delete action looks like this

```
def destroy
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  project.destroy

  redirect_to :root , status: :see_other
end
```

and the error being returned looks like this

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `root_url' for #<Api::V1::ProjectsController:0x0000000009b488>>"
```

I have tried :api_v1_root, and a few other variations but none have worked. So does anyone know how I can redirect correctly? Thanks!

EDIT:

I ran `rails routes | grep api` and got back:

```
api_v1_root GET    /api/v1(.:format)                                                                                 api/v1/projects#index
                           api_v1_videos GET    /api/v1/videos(.:format)                                                                          api/v1/videos#index
                                         POST   /api/v1/videos(.:format)                                                                          api/v1/videos#create
                            api_v1_video GET    /api/v1/videos/:id(.:format)                                                                      api/v1/videos#show
                                         PATCH  /api/v1/videos/:id(.:format)                                                                      api/v1/videos#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/videos/:id(.:format)                                                                      api/v1/videos#update
                                         DELETE /api/v1/videos/:id(.:format)                                                                      api/v1/videos#destroy
                         api_v1_projects GET    /api/v1/projects(.:format)                                                                        api/v1/projects#index
                                         POST   /api/v1/projects(.:format)                                                                        api/v1/projects#create
                          api_v1_project GET    /api/v1/projects/:id(.:format)                                                                    api/v1/projects#show
                                         PATCH  /api/v1/projects/:id(.:format)                                                                    api/v1/projects#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/projects/:id(.:format)                                                                    api/v1/projects#update
                                         DELETE /api/v1/projects/:id(.:format)                                                                    api/v1/projects#destroy
                    api_v1_project_types GET    /api/v1/project_types(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/project_types#index
                                         POST   /api/v1/project_types(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/project_types#create
                     api_v1_project_type GET    /api/v1/project_types/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/project_types#show
                                         PATCH  /api/v1/project_types/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/project_types#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/project_types/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/project_types#update
                                         DELETE /api/v1/project_types/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/project_types#destroy
```

I've used `api_v1_root` and `api_v1_root_path` and both return the error `<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [DELETE] \"/api/v1\">`

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to root_path` ?

Comment: @RockwellRice yes, unfortunately that doesn't work either.

Comment: "I have tried :api_v1_root" - what happens when you try that, because it should work. `redirect_to :api_v1_root` or `redirect_to api_v1_root_path`

Comment: As @Alex said, api_v1_root_path is probably the right answer. It would be helpful if you run rails routes | grep api and update your question with the output to better help you.

Comment: @Alex @oldmanowl so I've tried both of those but both times it returns ```#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [DELETE] \"/api/v1\">```

Comment: you still need to keep `status: :see_other` part

Comment: @Alex Yeah I haven't removed that

Comment: What you're doing here doesn't make sense on multiple levels. In an API you respond to a DELETE request with OK or NO CONTENT. The server should not be responsible for redirecting like in a classical app.

Comment: @max well I'm following the tutorial at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article so if it doesn't make sense i don't know why they would do that. Also I would imagine that the whole point of rerouting after delete is so that after you delete an object, you don't stay on the page of the deleted object...

Comment: Regarding the path, `api_v1_projects_path` sho.uld be the right one according to your `rails routes` output

Comment: @KevinB. What they are building in that tutorial isn't actually a real API. It's a classical app that's augmented with Turbo. Usually if you for example have a list of items in a "real" SPA you just remove the item from the DOM or you use client-side routing to refresh the view. The whole point of a real API is to detach the backend from the flow and intracies of the front and have it simply deliver and manipulate data.

Comment: Gotcha. I would still love to know how to make this work but what you are saying definitely makes sense.